# How to undo while in cua-mode using rectangle selection?

Tags: emacs, rectangles, undo, cua-mode

A short example:
While writing text I mistype an "f" ([Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1JKX.jpg))  and want to undo it using C-z. The result is a missing rectangle selection and the last line having still an "f" ([Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptBMd.jpg)).

```
abcdf       abcd
abcdf  -->  abcd
abcdf       abcdf
```

Instead I would like to keep the rectangle-selection and have no "f" remaining to continue typing.

```
abcdf       abcd
abcdf  -->  abcd
abcdf       abcd
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!